# Python: PyCharm IDE method chaining suggestions not working when using decorators

Tags: python, method-chaining

Given below code:

```
def method_friendly_decorator(method_to_decorate):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('I got args! Look:'.join(*args, **kwargs))
        method_to_decorate(self, *args, **kwargs)

        return self

    return wrapper


class DecorateMe(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.first_name: str = ''
        self.last_name: str = ''

    @method_friendly_decorator
    def print_first_name(self, first_name: str):
        self.first_name = first_name
        print(f'My first name is {first_name}')
        return self

    @method_friendly_decorator
    def print_last_name(self, last_name: str):
        self.last_name = last_name
        print(f'My last name is {last_name}')
        return self

    @method_friendly_decorator
    def print_full_name(self):
        print(f'My full name is {self.first_name} {self.last_name}')
        return self
```

I'd like to be able to do:

```
def test_naming():
    DecorateMe().print_first_name('Test').print_last_name('User')
```

When I ***do not*** use the decorators on the functions in the `DecorateMe` class, I can see the suggested functions available, like below:

[image]

But, if I keep the method decorators, then I don't get the suggestions any longer:

[image]

I'm wondering if this is just "how it works" or if I am doing something wrong here?

Keeping in mind that, when using the decorators, the `method chain still works if you know the exact method name` to use, but to me, that's defeating the purpose since the whole idea is to be able to see the available methods.

Comment: The title is misleading. The chain is still working just fine, just your IDE has lost the ability to suggest things due to insufficient type hints.

Comment: @deceze Thank you for the feedback. I admit I wasn't sure about the phrasing of the title, but I didn't know how else to phrase it. Please feel free to amend it or recommend a suggested change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the return type for your wrapper like this:

```py
def method_friendly_decorator(method_to_decorate):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs) -> "DecorateMe":  # Define return type here
        print('I got args! Look:'.join(*args, **kwargs))
        return method_to_decorate(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

Put `DecorateMe` in quotes to not get `NameError: name 'DecorateMe' is not defined`. This is called a [forward reference](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#forward-references), from PEP 484

Side note: Your wrapper is hard-coded to always return `self`, making the return statement in each method ignored. It should return the return value of the decorated function as I did above

[image]

Comment: Omw! I just needed to specify the return type! I actually posted this question with an incorrect `method_friendly_decorator`. I was testing with `return self` instead of `return method_to_decorate` and forgot to change back before I posted. Nevertheless, THANK YOU for outlining the simple fix for me. I was bumping head for about a week on this issue! :)

Comment: Hardcoding the class it returns is kind of besides the point of a decorator…

Comment: I agree but I'm unaware of a way to dynamically relay the type of the decorated method's owner